# Converting input with XOR 15

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

I'm trying to cipher input with three different type or ciphers, and I am completely stuck on XOR 15.

```
import string

def caesar(text, shift, alphabets):

    def shift_alphabet(alphabet):
        return alphabet[shift:] + alphabet[:shift]

    shifted_alphabets = tuple(map(shift_alphabet, alphabets))
    final_alphabet = ''.join(alphabets)
    final_shifted_alphabet = ''.join(shifted_alphabets)
    table = str.maketrans(final_alphabet, final_shifted_alphabet)
    return text.translate(table)

plaintext = input("Enter a sentence to encode: >")
shifted = int(input("Shift by how much? >"))

print("Caesar results:")
print("Original: ", plaintext)
print("Cipher: ",(caesar(plaintext, shifted, [string.printable])))

def rot13(text):
    return ''.join([chr((ord(letter) - 97 + 13) % 26 + 97)
                    if 97 <= ord(letter) <= 122
                    else letter
                for letter in text.lower()])
print("Rot13 results: ")
print("Original: ", plaintext)
print("Rot13:",(rot13(plaintext))) 


def xor(plaintext,number):
    L = list(plaintext)
    L2 = [ord(value) ^ number for value in L]
    return L2

i = plaintext.encode('utf-8')
xor_number = 00;
results = xor(plaintext,xor_number)
print ("XOR 15 results:")
print ("Original hex:", i.hex(' '))
print ("XOR 15 hex:",  results)
```

When I get my results back after the user input I am only getting the regular ascii value instead of an XOR 15 of the original hex. Where am I going wrong?

Current Results:

```
XOR 15 results:
Original hex: 41 42 44 20 78 79 7a 20 31 32 33 21
XOR 15 hex: [65, 66, 68, 32, 120, 121, 122, 32, 49, 50, 51, 33]
```

Expected Results:

```
XOR 15 results:
Original hex: 41 42 44 20 78 79 7a 20 31 32 33 21
XOR 15 hex: [be, bd, bc, df, 87, 86, 85, df, ce, cd, cc, de]
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code and provide us with an example for the input values, the current output and the expected output.

Comment: And why do you expect the parameter `number` in `xor` to be `15`? You call `xor` only once in your code and you don't provide the value `15` in the call.

Comment: @Matthias edited the post with the information you asked for. The 15 is the amount it should shift. I'm sorry I'm very new and don't know how to call that in my particular situation.

Comment: Your "expected results" seem to be a XOR with 255, *not* 15.

Comment: A 15 bit shift is not the same as an XOR.

Comment: @jasonharper How do I achieve my expected results?

Comment: You call the function with `xor(plaintext, xor_number)`. In the line before this call you define `xor_number = 0`. If you want to xor with `15` this should be `xor_number = 15` of course.

Comment: @Matthias I had figured that out thank you. How do I covert that data I get into hex?